# Select database's table with drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, authentication

I have 4 different different tables in my data base and I want to select the table from drop down list like when 1 will select user so it should select user table and when I select admin It should select admin table and login into admin table and redirect on admin page.

Actually I am using different different table for different users can anyone help me how to make do this thing please help me.

What I should do should I make a single table for all type of users or not?

and I am using **PHP with mysql**

Comment: For differnt type of user you can create single table in users table you can manage 1 field for usertype  in which you can manage differnt user roles. like (1 = "Admin" ,2="Member") as per your requirement then at login time based on usertype you can manage.

Comment: This is far too broad for SO. SO is for questions about specific coding issues. If you are having some issue please post the code and the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: "should I make a single table for all type of users?" Probably